# Apt-get for Cuda 6.5 Libraries

Tags: apt, cuda

I am trying to install Jetpack 1.1 for an Nvidia Jetson development card on a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.  This is a mostly automated process, but at one point fairly deep into the install the process halts with the following error message:

> Failed to install one or more of the following packages: g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf **cuda-toolkit-6-5 cuda-cross-armhf-6-5** libgomp1-armhf-cross. Please make sure they are correctly installed with apt-get command before continuing installation.

This is a fairly straightforward error message, and for three of the five named packages, I think I have successfully applied apt-get. The two bold pages yield the following responses:

```
   ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install cuda-toolkit-6-5
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   E: Unable to locate package cuda-toolkit-6-5
```

And similarly for cuda-cross-armhf-6-5

How can I help apt-get find this software?

Edit:  The CPU is an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3540M CPU @ 3.00GHz

Edit:  The Nvidia Jetson dev board is an ARM architecture board and my Ubuntu system is not.  However, Jetpack supports cross-compilation from x86 to ARM architectures.  What is not obvious to me is if i7-3540M, being x86-64, is sufficient.  But I strongly suspect it is on the basis of the following outdated dev blog, which sure looks like it's using amd64 as its base example:

[Parallel ForAll](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/nvidia-nsight-eclipse-edition-for-jetson-tk1/)

Comment: What are your CPU specs?

Comment: @DevRobot see edit above:  Intel i7-3540

Answer (score 0):

The packages that could not be installed are of the **ARM** architecture.

Your CPU is an Intel one, so such packages cannot be installed on it.

**EDIT** Jetpack is only available with NVIDIA Nsight Eclipse Edition when using the AMD architecture. The explanation is simple when looking at the required **.deb** package: `cuda-repo-ubuntu1204_6.0-37_amd64.deb`
 - it's an **AMD 64 bit** debian package.

Comment: The Nvidia Jetson is an ARM architecture, yes, but Jetpack supports (or at one time supported) cross-compilation from x386 to ARM:  http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/nvidia-nsight-eclipse-edition-for-jetson-tk1/

Comment: @Novak "Even if it is supposed to work under .i386, the required packages are ARM, so the long and short of it is: impossible."

Comment: but see above edits.

Comment: See new edits :)